# How to transmit alert variables by E-mail message

Tags: iot, alerts

I’m a newbie in AggreGate IoT platform and I’m trying to use its Alerts feature. I need to insert the name of the device that triggered the alert into the email message being sent.

I see some [Alert Examples](https://aggregate.digital/docs/en/ls_alerts_examples.htm) in the documentation but I can’t find the way to extract the context of the current device. I’ve tried to write the Alert Message expression like {env/context} or cell({env/context},"value") but it has no effect.

Please help me to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send e-mail when Alert rises or deactivates, but with your own subject and message format.

1. Open "Automatic Corrective Actions" tab
2. Add action "Execution type"  - Rise, "Action" - Send E-mail and click on "Parameters" field.
3. You should see e-mail sending parameters, such as Recipients, Subject, message, etc. You can write it by yourself or use bindings, in our case we will use bindings.
4. To get variables from alert we should use an expression  for ex.  "cell({env/value},"trigger")". This expression will return "Trigger message". You can get any variables that we have in Alert Event (see attached screenshot).
5. When you get variable value, you can use it with AggreGate expression language. For example, if you get *cell({env/value}, "context")* it will return context of the device for which this alert was set. You need to get name of this device, using context - you can write expression *cell(getVariable(cell({env/value}, "context"),"genericProperties"),"name")*.
   [image]

[image]

[image]